# Property requires a method to be defined

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create a SplitViewController view but I get the following warning:

Property splitViewController requires a method setSplitViewController to be defined -use @Synthesize,@dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implement.

**Here is the code**

```
///AppDelegate.h

 @class ViewController;
 @class DetailViewController;

 @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
{
UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
ViewController *viewcontroller;
DetailViewController *detailViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic,retain) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property(nonatomic,retain)  UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
@property (nonatomic,retain) ViewController *viewController;

@end

///AppDelegate.m"

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
 @synthesize splitviewController;
 @synthesize detailViewController;
- (void)dealloc
{
   [_window release];
   [_viewController release];
   [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   ViewController *rootViewController = [[ViewController alloc]   initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
   detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
   rootViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;    

   splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
   splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
   splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;

   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
}




///ViewController.h
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 @class DetailViewController;
 @interface ViewController : UITableViewController{
 DetailViewController *detailViewController;
 NSMutableArray *phone;
 }
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *phone;
@end



///ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

 @implementation ViewController
 @synthesize detailViewController,phone;

  - (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopoverView {
 return CGSizeMake(320, 600);
 }


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.phone = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"phone" ofType:@"plist"]] retain];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  - (void)viewDidUnload
{
 [super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
 }

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
 {
 return YES;
 }
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView {
  // Return the number of sections.
 return 1;
 }


 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [phone count];
 }


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

// Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
 }

// Configure the cell.
 cell.textLabel.text = [self.phone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 return cell;
 }
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  /*
   When a row is selected, set the detail view controller's detail item to the item associated with the selected row.
   */
 detailViewController.detailItem = [self.phone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
 - (void)dealloc {
 [detailViewController release];
 [super dealloc];
 }



  @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ur code, you haven't synthesized your `splitViewController` property. Since You have not synthesized it the property, the compiler is issuing a warning asking u to either synthesize the property so that it can generate setters and getters automatically for your convinienvce (You can use the generated setters and getters using `.` notation as in `self.splitViewController` so synthesize it as 
 `@synthesize splitViewController = _splitViewController`

or

implement your own custom setter and getter as

```
//setter
- (void)setSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)splitViewController_ {
    //assuming your property has retain identifier
    if (splitViewController != splitViewController_) {
        [splitViewController release];
        splitViewController = [splitViewController_ retain];
    }
}

//getter
- (UISplitViewController*)splitViewController {
    return splitViewController;
}
```

or

declaring the property as dynamic using `@dynamic splitViewController` . This means that the  setter and getter for the property will be provided from somewhere else.

**EDIT:**

replace`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in appDelegate.m with the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   _viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController's nib name" bundle:nil];
   UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:_viewController];
   detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
   rootViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;    

   splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
   splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, detailViewController, nil];
   splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;

   self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;
   return YES;
}
```

also edit the dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [_window release];
   [_viewController release];
   [splitViewController release];
   [detailViewController release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

And in viewController `viewDidLoad` replace self.phones line with this

> self.phone = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cell ONE",@"Cell TWO",@"Cell THREE",@"Cell FOUR",@"Cell FIVE",@"Cell SIX", nil];

this is just for testing that the array part is loading properly..so that you can see the cells if they are getting created. put a break point in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and see if its getting called

and then finally in `didSelect` see if the detailItem iVar is not nil.

And Yes, check the NIB names properly before loading them, and also that all outlets in the NIB are properly connected.

Cheers and Have fun.

Comment: I have tried with @dynamic the warning's are cleared but getting blank screen.See the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you misspelled splitViewController in your @synthesize statement -- you didn't capitalize the v.

You wouldn't run into this problem if you did it the easy way. There's no need for either the instance variables or the @synthesize statements any more -- you get both automatically when create the property.

Comment: Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more. what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

In your case add `@synthesize splitViewController = _splitViewController;` **and** `detailViewController = _ detailViewController;`

Here is useful code for, how can i add `UISplitViewController`.

```
/// AppDelegate.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, strong)  UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
@property (nonatomic, strong)  MasterViewController *masterVC;
@property (nonatomic, strong)  DetailViewController *detailVC;

@property (nonatomic, strong)  UINavigationController *mvcNavCon;
@property (nonatomic, strong)  UINavigationController *dvcNavCon;

@end


/// AppDelegate.m File

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.masterVC = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    self.mvcNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.masterVC];

    self.detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
    self.dvcNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.detailVC];

    self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.mvcNavCon, self.dvcNavCon,nil];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the my code please see it .Still it is showing blank screen .What is the problem in my code.

Comment: check ur code with my code ?? wt u miss ?? and also give specific BackGroundColor of view of Ur viewController

Comment: what is the prob with this.Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.